# Sharing session variables between Air desktop app and browser

Tags: session, apache-flex, coldfusion, air, session-variables

I have a RIA built with Flex 3 that I am turning into an Air desktop app in anticipation of Flash End of Life. So far so good, except for this:

At the moment, I am setting up session variables with Flash remoting from the browser window and open a link in a new tab in the browser using these session variables when flash remoting returns its value. 
That works very well in a browser.

However, if I load my swf in a desktop app, using mx:HTML, then I get an error message when the new page opens in the browser:
Element teacherID is undefined in SESSION.

Which is quite obvious, as the Air desktop app and the system browser do not share the same session variables.

Any suggestion appreciated. 
I could use URL variables instead of sessions, but that would imply a lot of rewriting, which I would rather avoid. Not to mention the security issues.

Comment: How do you generate the session in the first place?  Is it created in the Flash remoting code?  Can you share the session cookie somehow?  ... Failing any of that, could you add more details about your setup to your question?  Are you using the session values on the client side to determine the link to open, or are you depending on the new tab having the same session in order for *that* page to reflect the values you've passed?

Comment: The session is created in Flash remoting when the user logs in. Something like:

Comment: The session is created in Flash remoting when the user logs in. Something like:<cfset session.teacherId = arguments.teacherid /> .  Then I do not use the session value to determine which link to open, but the new cfm page I am opening will have a query like Select... where teachers.ID = #session.teacherid# . So yes, I am depending on the new tab having the same session values. Which works when it is all in browser but not when there is the Air app on one side and the browser on the other.

Comment: Will shared objects work? It's been a while and I don't remember how they work with AIR but they're the way you get separate swf's to communicate